# What does #include actually do?

Tags: c, include

In C (or a language based on C), one can happily use this statement:

```
#include "hello.h";
```

And voila, every function and variable in `hello.h` is automagically usable.

But what does it actually do? I looked through compiler docs and tutorials and spent some time searching online, but the only impression I could form about the magical `#include` command is that it "copy pastes" the contents of `hello.h` instead of that line. There's gotta be more than that.

Comment: If it's any consolation, the preprocessor may also insert implementation-specific annotations so that if/when debug info is generated, it gets the line numbers right. If it literally had the effect of a copy-paste, the debugger wouldn't know the "real" source file and line number. Also `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` have to be substituted as if before the copy-paste. As far as the meaning of the program is concerned, though, copy-paste is it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Logically, that copy/paste is exactly what happens.  I'm afraid there isn't any more to it.  You don't need the `;`, though.

Your specific example is covered by the spec, section **6.10.2 Source file inclusion**, paragraph 3:

> A preprocessing directive of the form
>
> **`# include`** `"`*q-char-sequence*`"` *new-line*
>
> causes the replacement of that directive by the entire contents of the source file identified by the specified sequence between the `"` delimiters.

Answer (score 6):

That (copy/paste) is exactly what `#include "header.h"` does.

Note that it will be different for `#include <header.h>` or when the compiler can't find the file `"header.h"` and it tries to `#include <header.h>` instead.

Comment: "Different" only in that it usually searches in different places and is mentally associated with (standard) library headers.

Comment: @delnan, they don't have to be different at all - all of the searches are performed in an "implementation-defined" manner, according to the spec.  The difference is that the `""` form falls back to the `<>` form if it doesn't work.  @pmg is totally correct.

Comment: Also "different" because there need not be a file named `"thing.h"` when you do `#include <thing.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no.  The compiler saves the original file descriptor on a stack and opens the `#include`d file; when it reaches the end of that file, it closes it and pops back to the original file descriptor.  That way, it can nest `#include`d files almost arbitrarily.

Comment: compiler pass in gcc for example knows nothing about #include, because it's preprocessor pass.

Comment: @fazo: In most cases, the distinction there is meaningless. If you need pedantry for some reason, I can go dig up an incomplete list of compilers and whether they use preprocessors or not.

Answer (score 0):

The `# include` statement "grabs the attention" of the pre-processor (the process that occurs before your program is actually compiled) and "tells" the pre-processor to include whatever follows the `# include` statement.

While the pre-processor can be told to do quite a bit, in this instance it's being asked to recognize a header file (which is denoted with a `.h` following the name of that header, indicating that it's a header).

Now, a header is a file containing C declarations and definitions of functions not explicitly defined in your code. What does this mean? Well, if you want to use a function or define a special type of variable, and you know that these functions/definition are defined elsewhere (say, the standard library), you can just include (`# include`) the header that you know contains what you need. Otherwise, every time you wanted to use a print function (like in your case), you'd have to recreate the print function.

If its not explicitly defined in your code and you don't `#include` the header file with the function you're using, your compiler will complain saying something like: *"Hey! I don't see where this function is defined, so I don't know what to with this undefined function in your code!"*.

Answer (score -1):

It's part of the preprocessor. Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Including_files. And yes, it's just copy and paste.

Answer (score -1):

This is a nice link to answer this question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4.aspx

Usually #include and #include "path-name" just differs in the order of the search of the pre processor