# Unknown override specifier, missing type specifier

Tags: c++

First, `Parameter.h`:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Parameter {
public:
    Parameter();
    ~Parameter();

private:
    string constValue;
    string varName;
};
```

And `Parameter.cpp`:

```
#include "Parameter.h"

using namespace std;

Parameter::Parameter() {};
Parameter::~Parameter() {};
```

I've brought these two files down to the barest of bones to get the errors that seem to be popping up. At the two private declarations for `string`s, I get the two errors:

```
'constValue': unknown override specifier
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

I've seen several questions with these errors, but each refers to circular or missing references. As I've stripped it down to what's absolutely required, I can see no circular references or references that are missing.

Any ideas?

Comment: The name should be `std::string`.

Comment: In all the (working) classes I've written, I've never put in the `std::`, instead relying on the `using namespace std;` in the .cpp file. Why would this one be any different?

Comment: The using declaration has to come before the use of the name.

Comment: @David Parady: No, `using namespace std;` in `.cpp` file, located as in your example above, has no effect on header files. Apparently in your other "classes you've written" you did it differently.

Comment: TL;DR `override specifier` and the rest is a red herring. A more informative error message would have been: `'constValue' unknown.`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As @Pete Becker points out in the comments, you need to qualify the name `string` as `std::string`:

```
private:
    std::string constValue;
    std::string varName;
```

The compiler just doesn't know what you're talking about, and it's the equivalent of just writing:

```
SomeGreatType myMagicalUniversalType
```

The compiler just doesn't know what type that is unless you've declared, hence the error

> missing type specifier - int assumed

You should read up about [why you should avoid `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

With regards to your question in the comments:

> In all the (working) classes I've written, I've never put in the std::, instead relying on the using namespace std; in the .cpp file. Why would this one be any different?

I can only infer that at some point before including "Parameter.h" that you had a `using namespace std`. E.g.:

```
// SomeType.h

#using namespace std

...

// Parameter.cpp
#include "SomeType.h"
#include "Parameter.h"
```

The compiler compiles things top-to-bottom, and [including essentially just replaces the `#include` with the contents of that file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735379/what-does-include-actually-do)

Comment: I think you're right, I had probably had some classes that included other classes that already had the `using namespace std` in my other working projects. I'll work on getting this fixed.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and [**avoid `#using namespace std`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Even if you are avoiding #using namespace std you may want to always use the std string, in which case you do #using std::string; and then you'll only have to type string and it'll know which you want.